# ClrMD - AttachToProcess Using AttachFlag.Invasive and AttachFlag.NonInvasive Crashing

Tags: c#, wpf, process, clrmd

I'm using the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime` nuget package and this is my code as I attempt to get the stacktrace:

```
var pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
// Line of error
using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000, AttachFlag.Invasive))
{
    ClrInfo currentRuntime = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0];
    var runtime = currentRuntime.CreateRuntime();
    foreach (var t in runtime.Threads)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Got here");
        t.StackTrace
    }
}
```

Question is similar to [Attach to self with ClrMD? HRESULT: 0x80070057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621896/attach-to-self-with-clrmd-hresult-0x80070057) but I go a step further and build the application using Wix. Then, I install the application on my desktop so it is running without Visual Studio and its debugger.

The messagebox doesn't show, as long as I put it after the line `using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000, AttachFlag.Invasive))`. If I put the messagebox before, the messagebox does show.

In the code, I get the error

```
Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.ClrDiagnosticsException: 'Could not attach to pid 624, HRESULT: 0x80070057'
```

I think I understand why `AttachFlag.Invasive` doesn't work when I run the application in Visual Studio because it's being debugged, but I don't understand why that line doesn't work after I build it with Wix and install it on my Desktop.

Again, as with the attached Stackoverflow post, `AttachFlag.Invasive` and `AttachFlag.NonInvasive` don't work, but `AttachFlag.Passive` does work.

Answer (score 0):

Like my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790758/7122901

You can use `DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach`. This method creates a snapshot of the process and create `DataTarget` from it. Example:

```
var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(processId))
{
}
```